# Cannot Update Amount when Initialize Vendor Payment (Suitetalk)

Tags: c#, netsuite

I have code to `Create a Vendor Payment` for a`Vendor Bill` like this :

```
InitializeRecord ir = new InitializeRecord();
ir.type = InitializeType.vendorPayment;
InitializeRef iref = new InitializeRef();
iref.typeSpecified = true;
iref.type = InitializeRefType.vendorBill;
iref.internalId = vendorBillId;
ir.reference = iref;

Login();
ReadResponse getInitResp = _service.initialize(ir);

if (getInitResp.status.isSuccess)
{
    Record rec = getInitResp.record;
    ((VendorPayment)rec).total = (double)amount; //I don't want to pall all, just pay a half or just an amount less than the total
    ((VendorPayment)rec).totalSpecified = true;
    WriteResponse writeRes = _service.add(rec);
    return writeRes.status;
}
```

That can create a payment but the total is not apply, the payment is pay all amount of vendor bill's total.

I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: you mean to say you want to pay partial amount in the bill, but, the code above pays 100% of the bill amount?

Comment: I would suggest stepping through the code using the debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While applying payments to bill you cannot change the body level amount field. you got to change the `amount` line level field on `apply` line item record. I am not sure on syntax in Suitetalk, but, that should work.

Comment: Yes @Prasun, I just want to pay partial amount of the bill, can we do that ?

Comment: yes, like I said if you are able to change line level amount field